# Who to contact to identify source of and address excessive humidity in house?

Tags: moisture

My house, a 1947 cape in Massachusetts, is always much more humid that outside, in all seasons.  Even when running the dehumidifier, one in the basement, and one on each of the two main levels, it rarely falls below 50%, even when outside is only in the teens or 20s.  I've had a few outbreaks of mold, when I failed to run the dehumidifier regularly.  This is an issue that is too big for me to address.  So, I'd like to bring in an expert to assess and address the situation.  Yet, I haven't been able to find one.  Who should I call in a situation like this?  Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to address water (vapor, at least) getting in through the basement and perhaps also address an upgraded dehumidification system covering the whole house. Which is likely 2 if not 3 contractors, I don't know of a likely one-call solution. *i.e.* you may need to address water on the outside of/below the foundation (drainage;) sealing the basement walls/floor; and if the problem persists, moving to a whole-house dehumidification system (if you have not already done so, I recommend setting up your presumably portable dehumidifiers to run to a piped drain.)

Comment: Ecnerwal: That is a great comment and think you should convert it to an answer.

Comment: In addition, you should check that you do not have venting issues with any appliances that might be down there like a furnace or water heater. Some models generate a lot of moisture.

Comment: I agree with the piped dehumidifier the smaller models you have to empty or they overflow/ shutdown we were able to use a floor drain on our home with the most moisture that model did a great job but cost close to 40$ per month, that was a lot back then but it ran all the time prior to coating the floor.

Answer (score 1):

I had a home in Ohio with a basement that had high humidity a large dehumidifier running 24-7 pulled an amazing amount of moisture out of the air. Late in the summer we epoxy painted the floor with a 2 part epoxy and this alone greatly reduced the moisture in the house.

We had taped plastic down in 5 places in the basement for 24 hours  to see if there were places that were worse (the front of the house was very wet, we had to wait until summer for the moisture to be low enough to paint (according to the directions) after that we did not need the big dehumidifier coating the floor but we still did use a much smaller model , I have coated quite a few basement floors since then all with similar results so you may give this a try.

Comment: Did you find a brand that you felt offered better results than the others?

Comment: I did find the 2 part epoxy for garage floors by rustolium was the best , the first time I used it I only read the application instructions not all the warnings , I used it on the house basement and it really stank for several days. I later found it was not recommended for living spaces unless they could be vented for 48-72 hours. That basement took 4 gallons but after it cured it changed the comfort of the whole house , we no longer had mold growing on basement windows and the smaller dehumidifier probably paid for the coating. That was in the early 80’s there may be better but I still use it